# get data from elements inside each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.post-type-archive-product .elementor-grid > div.e-loop-item').each(function() {
    
    setTimeout( function() {
    
        var get_prod_name = $('.product_title > a', this).text();
        var get_prod_sku = $('div.sku_wrapper > .sku', this).text();

        console.log(get_prod_sku);

    }, 500);
        
});
```

Can someone help me with pointing what I'm doing wrong here... in a `each` loop, I'm trying to get 2 datas inside variables `get_prod_name` and `get_prod_sku`... but it's not working at all... it just shows blank(no info)... although there is info in all of the 28 blocks in the each loop

Comment: here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ka9m7nfu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is in the context that you're using it.  Note the use of `setTimeout`, so by the time that code runs (500ms later) you're no longer in the context of the callback to `.each()`.

You can capture the value of `this` in a variable and use that variable instead, for example:

```js
$('.post-type-archive-product .elementor-grid > div.e-loop-item').each(function() {

  // capture it here
  var self = this;

  setTimeout( function() {
    var get_prod_name = $('.product_title > a', self).text();
    var get_prod_sku = $('div.sku_wrapper > .sku', self).text();
    console.log(get_prod_sku);
  }, 500);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-type-archive-product">
  <div class="elementor-grid">
    <div class="e-loop-item">
      <div class="product_title">
        <a href="#">one</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sku_wrapper">
        <div class="sku">two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="product_title">
        <a href="#">three</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sku_wrapper">
        <div class="sku">four</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```